# flash as3 fullscreen browser jams up playback

Tags: actionscript-3, browser, flash-cs5, fullscreen, playback

I have an AS3 project which when the user clicks a button the browser is set to fullscreen.  This works great, however the playback sticks after the navigation is sent to the next frame.  The MC on frame two plays, but then the playback head doesn't move forward to frame 3.  Once escape is pressed, the fullscreen is broken and then the movie skips to where it would have been normally if it hadn't have gotten stuck on frame two (as if the project was running in the background).  This problem also occurs without the fullscreen AS3, just using the controls for a projector to go to fullscreen, and it also occurs if the .swf file plays back directly in a flashplayer without the browser.  I don't understand, without fullscreen, everything plays back perfectly....

Here's the code on frame 1:

```
fullscreenMe.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, fullScreenIt); 

function fullScreenIt(event:MouseEvent):void {
MovieClip(root).gotoAndPlay('two');
stage.displayState=StageDisplayState.FULL_SCREEN;}
```

And here's the code on frame 2:

```
var titlesTimer = new Timer(11000,1); 
titlesTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, titlesTimerFinished);
titlesTimer.start();

function titlesTimerFinished(e:TimerEvent):void {
//trace("timer is finished");   
MovieClip(root).nextFrame();
}

var creditsSound:credits = new credits();
var creditsChannel:SoundChannel = new SoundChannel();
creditsChannel = creditsSound.play();
```

And here's the code on frame 3:

```
import fl.transitions.Tween;
import fl.transitions.easing.*;

function alphaTween(mc,b,f,d) {
    var Alpha:Tween = new Tween(mc, "alpha", Regular.easeIn, b, f, d, true);
}

alphaTween(moon1,0,1,7);

var moonTimer = new Timer(1000,7);
moonTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, moonTimerFinished);
moonTimer.start();

function moonTimerFinished(e:TimerEvent):void {
//trace("timer is finished");   
MovieClip(root).nextFrame();

}
```

Comment: Pressing ESC will always take you out of full screen. It is a security feature.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm from the information given I am not sure if the Playhead is in play mode or stop mode in a frame.

Before we can solve it

1. Is there a `this.stop();` command added before any code is written in the frame. This ensures the Playhead is not in playing mode and stops in the present frame. If you want it playing, then no issues. But looking at the timers, I assume you must have added the stop() command.
2. [Documentation](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/MovieClip.html#nextFrame%28%29) for MovieClip for nextFrame says it sends the playhead to the next frame and stops it. This happens after all remaining actions in the frame have finished executing. So is this intended?

Comment: O.k. so each of these three frames has a stop action associated with it --sorry for omitting that info.  As for the nextFrame, when the playback is NOT in fullscreen, it moves to nextFrame once the timer finishes, where it encounters a stop action and another timer which when finished again moves the playback head to nextFrame where it stops and goes through the process all over again. I tried to change the code to gotoAndPlay('frameName'), but the playback chokes so I reverted to nextFrame which works (except in fullscreen)....